# Convert number to scientific notation and obtain exponent

Tags: c#

How can I convert a number to scientific notation and obtain the exponent? For example if I have 23582 and want to convert it to 2.3582 x 10^4 and then obtain the '4' which is the order of the number? (I'm using C#)

Comment: This is just taking the [log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.log10(v=vs.110).aspx) (base 10) of the number.

Comment: How about read this first : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx and combine it using "string.Split" and "int.Parse"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the result can be negative in case the number is **less that 1** so we use `Math.Floor` to handle that:

```
int exponent = num == 0 ? 0 : (int)Math.Floor((Math.Log10(Math.Abs(num))));
```

Comment: `Math.Abs(num)` within logarithm; do not forget about `num == 0` case

Comment: There is one too many set of parentheses around Math.Log10(). 

(It wouldn't let me suggest an edit since it's below the edit limit of 6 characters.)

Answer (score 2):

Just use *logarithm*:

```
  int exponent = value == 0
    ? 0 // special case: technically it should be -infinity 
    : (int) Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value)));
```

Comment: I don't think this handles numbers that are less than 1. eg `0.2`

Comment: @user3185569: you're right; `Math.Floor` or alike is required

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below notation,

```
int number = 23582;
            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("G2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output is,

```
2.4E+04
```